# Segmentation fault when using semaphore from shared memory block

Tags: c, process, mutex, semaphore, shared-memory

I am trying to create a program using shared memory blocks and obviously I have to lock them with semaphores. However I'm getting a segmentation fault when trying to initialise it (same thing happends with mutex). I have no idea what am I doing wrong here. Code looks like this:

```
//struct communicator_t {
//    sem_t semaphore;
    ////////////////

//};

struct communicator_t *playerCommunicator;
//

void createCommunicator(void) {

    key_t key = ftok(FILE_CONTROLLER, 0);
    int sharedBlockId = shmget(key, sizeof(struct communicator_t),
                               IPC_CREAT);

    playerCommunicator =
            (struct communicator_t *) shmat(sharedBlockId, NULL, 0);
   sem_init(&playerCommunicator->semaphore, 0, 1);


}
```

Comment: The man page for `sem_init` seems to say the second argument should be 1 for what you're doing.

Comment: OK, but I keep getting segm fault, so the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Check the return values, I guess.